# Not all functions are being called from config.xml

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, configuration

I have few functions which I want to call from my **config.xml**, like so:

```
<firegento_pdf_invoice_edit_page>
            <observers>
                <firegento_pdf>
                    <class>firegento_pdf/observer</class>
                    <method>addInvoiceBarcode</method>
                </firegento_pdf>
            </observers>
            <observers>
                <firegento_pdf>
                    <class>firegento_pdf/observer</class>
                    <method>addBankDetails</method>
                </firegento_pdf>
            </observers>
            <observers>
                <firegento_pdf>
                    <class>firegento_pdf/observer</class>
                    <method>addLogo</method>
                </firegento_pdf>
            </observers>
</firegento_pdf_invoice_edit_page>
```

The two functions which I've created are **addBankDetails** and **addLogo**, they're both in my **Observer.php** file. I've placed an error log in each function, to check whether they are being called, but only addLogo is being called. I'm unsure what to do to resolve this.

EDIT: Here are the 3 functions I'm using:

```
public function addInvoiceBarcode(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('sales_pdf/invoice/order_id_as_barcode')) {
        return $this;
    }
    return $this->_addBarcode($observer);
}

public function addBankDetails(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    error_log(print_r("addBankDetails", true), 3, '/var/www/html/error.log');
    $page = $observer->getPage();
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($observer->getOrder()->getCustomerId());
    $customerGroup = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($customer->getGroupId())->getId();
    $allowedCustomerGroups = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales_pdf/firegento_pdf/enable_bank_details');
    $allowedCustomerGroupsArray = explode(',', $allowedCustomerGroups);

    //if the customer is one of the enabled customer groups from the config settings, add the bank details to the PDF
    if (in_array($customerGroup, $allowedCustomerGroupsArray)){
        $bankDetails = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales_pdf/firegento_pdf/bank_details');
        //seperate by newline
        $lineSeperation = 15;
        $textLineArray = explode("\n", $bankDetails);
        foreach($textLineArray as $textLine){
            $page->drawText($textLine, 32, 250 - $lineSeperation, 'UTF-8');
            $lineSeperation += 15;
        }
    }
    return $this;
}

public function addLogo(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $page = $observer->getPage();
    $pageHeight = $page->getHeight();
    $pageWidth = $page->getWidth();
    $startWidth = $pageWidth/4;
    $imgPath = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales_pdf/firegento_pdf/factoryx_logo_image');
    $logo = "media/logo/" . $imgPath;
    $logoSize = getimagesize(Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . "logo/" . $imgPath);
    $logoWidth = $logoSize[0];
    $logoHeight = $logoSize[1];
    error_log(print_r($logoHeight, true), 3, '/var/www/html/error.log');
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($observer->getOrder()->getCustomerId());
    $customerGroup = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($customer->getGroupId())->getId();
    $allowedCustomerGroups = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales_pdf/firegento_pdf/factoryx_logo');
    $allowedCustomerGroupsArray = explode(',', $allowedCustomerGroups);
    //if the image has been uploaded
    if ($imgPath != "") {
        $logo = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($logo);
        //if the customer is one of the enabled customer groups from the config settings, add the fx logo
        if (in_array($customerGroup, $allowedCustomerGroupsArray)){
            $page->drawImage($logo, $startWidth, $pageHeight-$logoHeight, $startWidth+$logoWidth, $pageHeight);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: are you using a single event i.e 'firegento_pdf_invoice_edit_page' for all three methods ?

Comment: Yes I am, is that the wrong thing to do?

Comment: I think yes,  see my answer with comments, let me know if it workd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use unique identifiers when defining observes

Try something like this

```
<firegento_pdf_invoice_edit_page>
    <observers>
        <firegento_pdf_add_invoice_bar_code>
            <class>firegento_pdf/observer</class>
            <method>addInvoiceBarcode</method>
        </firegento_pdf_add_invoice_bar_code>
    </observers>
    <observers>
        <firegento_pdf_add_bank_details>
            <class>firegento_pdf/observer</class>
            <method>addBankDetails</method>
        </firegento_pdf_add_bank_details>
    </observers>
    <observers>
        <firegento_pdf_add_logo>
            <class>firegento_pdf/observer</class>
            <method>addLogo</method>
        </firegento_pdf_add_logo>
    </observers>
</firegento_pdf_invoice_edit_page>
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you very much Priyank :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to add multiple  tag for single event.
You can call method inside main observed method.

If you are listing a single event you can call multiple method in single observer like:

**config.xml**

```
<events>
 <firegento_pdf_invoice_edit_page><!-- observe the event -->
   <observers>
    <firegento_pdf>
        <class>firegento_pdf/observer</class>
        <method>addInvoiceBarcode</method>
        </firegento_pdf>
   </observers>
 </firegento_pdf_invoice_edit_page>
</events>
```

**Observer.php**

```
class Firegento_Pdf_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
    {

      public function addInvoiceBarcode($observer)
      {
          //some code;
          $this->addBankDetails($observer);

      }
      public function addBankDetails($observer)
      {
          //some code;
          $this->addLogo($observer);
      }
      public function addLogo($observer)
      {
          //some code;
          return "here";
      }
    }
```

Comment: It won't let me call addBankDetails from addInvoiceBarcode, I get the error "FireGento_Pdf_Model_Observer::addBankDetails() must be an instance of Varien_Event_Observer"

Comment: I will amend my OP to include the functions I'm using

Comment: I have put die on each function and it is working.

Comment: Hi Pawan, thank you so much for your help. The answer below solved my issue though.

Comment: Jack, as you are using $observer in other method, you need to send this as a parameter to with function and it will work.

Comment: Good to know, You got solution.